# why would a post apocalyptic exploration team want a Teenager in their group?

Tags: post-apocalypse, exploration

So for the setting :

- the world is recovering of a mass apocalyptic event
- the place in which where all of the mankind steading, is actually a small communities and towns centered around a city of goverment authority
- the goverment want to send a exploration team a la louis and clark style to explore the outside world.

now for my question :
why would they, the goverment want,or keep, a teenager in this exploration team ?

Comment: Seems like this is a question about the motivation and decisions of a character or organization in your world rather than building your world.

Comment: Because teenagers are expendable? Human history has used teenagers to explore new lands, new foods, new experiences. If they survive, they have better genes.

Comment: I wanted to edit your question, but wonder what the following things mean: 1) "the "world" is actually.." - 'actually' according to the people living in the communities or 'actually' in actuality, physically? 2) What is "centred around" - are the communities in the centre of a city, or are they positioned around a city? Is "government authority" an authoritarian or authoritative government? "Louis and Clark" as in 'the Lewis and Clark expedition' or as in 'Lois & Clark' (in which case: how?)?

Comment: This is a question about your story, but you can change it to ask expert opinions in here by asking what would cause a town to need teenagers for dangerous exploration missions outside. As it is, you should ask this at the Writing stack exchange. Vote to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer:

I suggest a few reasons why fictional post apocalytic exploring expediton might include one or more teenage members like most historical exploring expedtions did.

Long Answer:

Six Parts with six suggestions why fictional post apocalytic exploring expediton might include one or more teenage members like most historical exploring expeditons did.

Part One:  Teenagers in More Dangerous Situtations than Exploring.

The military is one such occupation.

A teenager is usally defined as someone whose age ends with "teen". There is a big difference between most people on their 13th birthdays and their 20th birthdays.  In the last few decades the age of legal adulthood has been lowered to 18 in most countries, so today millions of persons are both teenages and legal adults.

And even before the age of adulthood was lowered to 18, 18-year-olds served in the miltary, even in times of war, and even in combat, which was probably a more dangerous occupation than going on exploring expeditions.

Do you know how many teenagers served in the US Civil War?  You don't.  I am something of an expert, and can say with certainty that nobody knows.  At that time the regulations for the US Army (the regular army) put the age of enlistment as 21 to 35.  But boys between 18 and 20 could enlist with the permission of parents or guardians.  And there was no maximum age limit for soldiers reenlisting.  And no lower age limit for "musicians" - drummers, buglers, fifers, trumpeters.

Most of the US forces in the Civil War were members of the other army of the federal government, the United States Volunteers.  And the regulations gave the same lower limits of 21 and 18 as for the regular army, and didn't mention the ages of musicians at all.

Of course the ages of almost all soldiers were officially recorded when they enlisted.  But I have found that it was very common to exaggerate the ages of drummer boys by a few years in their official records.  And I have found 2 or 3 cases where a boy who was 12 was recorded as being 18, and one case where a 9-year-old was recorded as 18!  In addiiton to boy musicians, there is strong evidence that tens or hundreds of thousands of boys younger than 18 lied about their ages and served as privates during the war.

About 212 men of the 7th Cavalry were killed in Custer's Last Stand on June 25, 1876. Sometime ago I read somewhere that studies of some of their bones indicated that some may have been as young as 14,and thus would have been much younger than the official ages.  I assume that they probably looked old for their ages.  And it is well known that Custer's 18-year-old nephew, a civilian employee, was amoung the killed.

I also read another study of the ages of surviving members of the 7th cavalry.  For about 100 of them they found statements of their ages in census records and other records from their later lives.  And they found that most of the soldiers who gave their ages as 21 when they enlisted were younger than that according to their ages in later records.  The extreme example enlisted in 1875 at a reported age of 21, but was actually 14, an example of exaggerating age by 7 years and 50 percent.

I remember a statement by someone in General Crook's army during war thatt a certain fact (which I don't remember) was known to everyone, from the General down to the youngest bugler, implying some buglers were teenagers.  I also note that some of the Crow Indian allies in Crook's army brought along their young wives, and some of those wives brought their babies along on the expedition!

Similarly, in the British navy, there were enlisted boys aged 16 and 17 and midhispmen aged 16 to 18 serving in combat in World War I.  I believe that the thousands of British sailors killed at Jutland in 1816 included about a hundred boys and midshipmen aged 16 to 18.

And there were still boys in that age range serving in World War II.   On the night of October 13-14, 1939, German sub U-47 (whose crew must have included teenagers, since its average age was 20) snuck into the heavily guarded anchorage of the British fleet at Scapa Flow and torpedoed HMS *Royal Oak*.  835 died, including Admiral Blaglove and 134 boy seamen under 18, the largest such loss in a singe Royal Navy action.  I note that the marine detachments aboard some Royal Navy ships in World War II included 14-year-old buglers.

There are still examples of rebels and even some governments using teenage and even child soldiers, capable of handling lightweight modern weapons, in armed conflicts in the third world.

So possibly a post apocalyptic expedition might be sent by some third world society whose leaders were used to forcing teenage and younger boys and girls to do something as dangerous as fighting and so wouldn't think twice about sending any kids who can be even the slightest bit of use - as child prostitutes to other expediiton members, for example - on even the most dangerouse exploring expediiton.

Part two: Kids on Exploring Expeditions.

I note that many government sponsored exploring expeditions in history were mostly composed of military or and naval personnel.  And I have to wonder whether the proportion of teenage boys in such expeditions was smaller or larger than in the armed forces as a whole.

And have you examined the personnel records of historic exploring expeditions?  What is the earliest exploring expedition you have found where there weren't any teenage members?

Several decades ago I read about uncovering bones of dead members of the lost Franklin Expedition in Arctic Canada.  It was mentioned that at least one set of bones belonged to some aged 12 to 15.  Since they died 3 years after the expediiton sailed, that individual was aged 9 to 12 when they sailed.

However, a few years ago it was recently claimed that genetic tests on some remains of the Franklin expedition revealed that some were females!  If that is true possibly the small bones of a boy 12 to 15 years old actually the bones of a young woman or maybe a teenage girl, maybe older or maybe about the same age.

The Lews and Clark expedition included soldiers:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_and_Clark_Expedition#Departure

> While accounts vary, it is believed the Corps had as many as 45 members, including the officers, enlisted military personnel, civilian volunteers, and Clark's African-American slave York.[46]

And one or more of the soldiers could have been teenagers. Clark's older brother George Rogers Clark (1752-1818) captured the Illinois country in 1778-79, and Clark's expedition included a 14-year-old drummer small enough to stay dry crossing water by floating on his drum.

Reaching a Mandan village in 1804, Lewis and Clark hired trapper Toussaint Charboneau and one of his wives who was a Shoshonie Indian who could interpret.  She was Sacagawea (c. 1788-1812 or 1884), who gave birth to her son on Feb. 11, 1805.  Teenage Sacagawea and her baby accompanied the expedition, demonstrating its peaceful intent to many groups they met, and went all the way to the Pacific Ocean and back to the Mandan village.

So even if regular expediton personenel don't include teenagers, teenage guides or interpreters might picked up along the way.

Part Three: Kids Working, So Why Not Send Them Exploring?

There are many ethnic groups with different customs in Nigeria.  I have read that in some of the towns, the custom is for adults to stay at home, and send their children out to the market and on other business, and this clashes with sending the kids to school. And possibly after the apocalypse that society might revert to that custom, and so if sends out an exploring expedition might send a lot of kids in it.

I once saw a tv news program about Naples, Italy, and according to it many Neapolitan adults are unemployed, but there is a lot of child labor in various occupations there.  So possibly after the apocalypse it might seem natural for a Neapolitan exploring expedition to include some kids.

According to *The Black Ship*, by Dudley Pope, some of the officers and crew of HMS *Hermione* were boys during the bloody mutiny in 1797.  It tells how one 14-year-old sailor had been a clerk to a business in one of the British East Indies.  His boss sent him on business to another island, either because he had faith in his ability, or because the boy would be a small loss if something happened to his ship.  His ship was captured by French privateers, who were then captured by a Royal Navy ship, and the boy was impressed into the navy.  This is an example of a boy civilian being sent on a dangerous journey by his boss.

So maybe your fictional post apocalyptic exploring expedition will have to rent a boat, or pack mules, or a wagon, or some other equipment, from a private citizen.  And maybe the private citizen will send a teenage boy along to take care of the equipement and keep the explorers from braking or abandoning it, figuring it would be better if his boy employee faced danger instead of himself.

Part Four: Adults Not Caring if Child Workers live or Die.

There are many examples in history of slave owners and employers having extremely little regard for the safety of the slaves and employees.

For example, I once read a historical article explainying why the Virginia colonly did not increase much in numbers for years while new colnists kept arriving from England. John Rolfe began to cultivate tobbaco in Virgiana from seeds smuggled from Spanish Trinidad in 1611, and tobacco exports soon became the foundation of the Virginia colony's economy. MOst of the poer colonists paid for their passage by becoming e indentured survants to wealthier men who would pay for them, and then would have to work their masters for a number of years.

According to the article it was easy to grow enough corn to feed oneself in Viriginia.  But the tobbacco planters had their employeees grow inadequade amounts of corn, and spend the rest of their time growing tobacco for export.

When winter came, there would be enough stored corn for the planeters and their families, but not enough to keep the workers well feed over the winter.  The malnoursished workers succumbed to hunger, cold and disease, and mostly died before the spring planting season.  Fortunately for the planters, new workers would arrive from England about that time to start the cycle over again.

As I remember the article claimed that many of the indentured servants arriving  from England were teenage boys from the slums of London.  There was a benevolent socity formed to rescue boys from the streets to send them to Virginia in hope of a better life, little knowing that the masters of those boys would basically murder them to grow more tobacco for more money.

So if that article is correct, Virginia actually had a labor system even more evil than slavery before it adopted slavery, and there is no lower limit to how little some bosses might care about the well being of their child and teenage employees.

Part Five:  Teenage Interests Vital to the Misssion.

I also note that in a post apocalyptic society, some teenagers might be the only persons interested enough in various sciences to read and study left over science books.  So teenagers might be the only persons in the society who know how to identify dangerous animals, edible planets, and valuable minerals, for exmaple, in the territory the expediton will explore.

Part Six:  Science Fiction Type Abilities of Teenagers.

Science fiction is full of stories where chldren and teenagers rare and unsual and useful skills.a bilities, and powers.

I remember Robert A. Heinlein's novel *Time For the Stars*, 1956.  Earth sends slower-than-light expeditions to nearby stars to search for habitable planets to colonize, and uses twin telepaths to send messages instantly.  So it recruits young adult and teenage telephaths to go on the shipsa nd age slowly through time dilation while their twins age normally over the deacades and are still alive all through the mission.

The teenage telepathic narrator mentioned another telepath, Dusty Rhodes, who was preteen, and wonder why his parents allowed such a young boy to go on such a dangerous voyage, speculating that perhaps they actually hoped that bratty Dusty would be killed.

Conclusions.

Those are my suggesitons for possibly reasons why a ficitonal post apocalytic explooring expediton might include one or more teenage members like most historical exploring expeditons.

Comment: As always, your answers always is the best ! definitely green check this one !.

Answer (score 3):

A similar reason to Orson Scott Card's "Enders Game", in which a teenager (Ender) saves the world. They covertly searched for a genius strategist to fight an overwhelming alien threat, using video games with prize. Ender consistently won these games with surprising original strategies, some of them designed by generals to be unwinnable.

You need a similar thing, your Teenager has some undeniable skill at something and the team is willing to take whatever hits are needed to have her on board. It doesn't have to be strategy, it could be something like languages, she can pick up new languages in a day, be fluent in a week. In a more primitive setting, perhaps she is an astounding tracker. Or maybe she is a world champion marksmen, with a gun, or arrows, or a sling for that matter.

Give her a reason to be there, a crucial role to play, and she is a savant that crushes any adult they can find.

Answer (score 3):

Because teenagers are younger, and as a result more physically fit and mentally flexible than an adult. A teenager would have faster reaction times and might see solutions the adults would overlook. They might not be very wise, but the adults in the group would help comphensate for that.

Answer (score 1):

## The teenager is the only expert of a legacy system that exists.

The government wants to retrieve and use some old computers and machines that use a long since redundant piece of software. This teen was part of a family that helped maintain this critical infrastructure, but the rest of their family was lost in the apocalypse.

They are the only one who knows how the system works, and thus are key to the expedition.